# Javascript template in react native 0.71.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

React native 0.71.0 by default comes with typescript. How i can create a javascript template with react native 0.71.0?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pure javascript option, but javascript can be used.

> Files with a .jsx extension are treated as JavaScript instead of TypeScript, and will not be typechecked.

See [Using JavaScript Instead of TypeScript](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#using-javascript-instead-of-typescript).